# How to use enum values in a rand() function

Tags: c++, random, enums

How can I use a rand function that generates a random enumerated variable? This is what I so far have (it's spitting out garbage numbers):

```
enum pieces { FLAG = 'F', BOMB = 'B', MARSHAL = '1', GENERAL = '2', COLONEL = 
              '3', MAJOR = '4', CAPTAIN = '5', LIEUTENANT = '6', SERGEANT = 
              '7', MINER = '8', SPY = 'S' };

int gamePieces[12] = { FLAG, BOMB, MARSHAL, GENERAL, COLONEL, MAJOR, 
                       CAPTAIN, LIEUTENANT, SEGEANT, MINOR, SPY };

int rand_piece = (rand()& gamePieces[12];
```

Comment: try `gamePieces[rand() % 12]`

Comment: Your code is full of errors. Misspelt  SEGEANT, MINOR,  missing closing bracket in rand_piece, the number of enums 11 while the size declared 12.

Answer (score 1):

Probably is is not possible strictly. 
You can

1. check what values have these enums in integers
2. then you will be able to generate an integer
3. do a modulo on it (%)
4. parse to enum [edit - you don't have to parse it to enum in C++]

eg.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>  
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   enum gamePieces { FLAG, BOMB, MARSHAL, GENERAL, COLONEL, MAJOR, 
                       CAPTAIN, LIEUTENANT, SEGEANT, MINOR, SPY };

   int maxEnumValue = 12;
   int randPiece = rand() % maxEnumValue;
   cout << randPiece;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rand() % 12`, this will create a random number in the range 0-11:

```
int rand_piece = gamePieces[rand() % 12];
```

---

There are more errors in your code - try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

const int numPieces = 11;

enum pieces { FLAG = 'F', BOMB = 'B', MARSHAL = '1', GENERAL = '2', COLONEL = 
              '3', MAJOR = '4', CAPTAIN = '5', LIEUTENANT = '6', SERGEANT = 
              '7', MINER = '8', SPY = 'S' };

int gamePieces[numPieces] = { FLAG, BOMB, MARSHAL, GENERAL, COLONEL, MAJOR, 
                       CAPTAIN, LIEUTENANT, SERGEANT, MINER, SPY };

int rand_piece = gamePieces[rand() % numPieces];
```

Or if you don't need the extra value:

```
enum pieces { FLAG, BOMB, MARSHAL, GENERAL, COLONEL, MAJOR, 
              CAPTAIN, LIEUTENANT, SERGEANT, MINER, SPY,
              MAX_PIECE };

int rand_piece = rand() % MAX_PIECE;
```

Comment: here's the error I got with that:
---------------------------------------
     ex.cpp:88:44: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     int rand_piece = gamePieces[rand() % 12];

Comment: @Gbrandonconner There were some more errors in your code. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int main()
{
    enum pieces {
        FLAG = 'F', BOMB = 'B', MARSHAL = '1', GENERAL = '2', COLONEL =
        '3', MAJOR = '4', CAPTAIN = '5', LIEUTENANT = '6', SERGEANT =
        '7', MINER = '8', SPY = 'S'
    };

    int gamePieces[11] = { FLAG, BOMB, MARSHAL, GENERAL, COLONEL, MAJOR,
        CAPTAIN, LIEUTENANT, SERGEANT, MAJOR, SPY };


    std::cout << char(gamePieces[rand() % 11]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << char(gamePieces[rand() % 11]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << char(gamePieces[rand() % 11]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << char(gamePieces[rand() % 11]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << char(gamePieces[rand() % 11]) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
7
4
4
B
6
```